# Get and set a package stream in password-protected OOXML files

Tags: c#, .net, vba, openxml, system.io.packaging

Currently, we are using Sysyem.IO.Packaging namespace to get macros from various Office files.

```
Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var pp = package.GetParts().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ContentType.Equals(@"application/vnd.ms-office.vbaProject"));
if (pp != null)
{
     ProcessMacros(pp.GetStream());
     ...
```

Similarly we save it back to the file in the end.
However, this does not work for password-protected files. Is there a way to get/update the vbaProject stream programmatically by providing the valid password?
Any 3rd party helper tools for that?

Comment: Are you talking about VBA Project password?

Comment: @FaneDuru - No, the Microsoft Office files themselves are password-protected.

Comment: Are you doing it to fix for 32/64 bits installations? Or are you referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-ovba/ef7087ac-3974-4452-aab2-7dba2214d239)?

Comment: @Sgdva - None of those. We have a software that modifies the content of macros included in Office files. The code that does this job is already written and it is being done inside "ProcessMacros" method. Now, the problem is that it is not possible to get the package parts if the file is password-protected. The alternative may be to "unzip" the OOXML Office file in some temp location and get the stream from there, but I don't see a way how the modified version can be easily later be updated in the original file. That's why I'm searching for tools that will just get the password and do that.

Comment: I am afraid it may not be possible since Microsoft does not keep the password in plain text (anymore) and use Compound File Binary File Format. Please, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/archive/blogs/openspecification/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents) something about the issue in discussion. Since you try opening it **knowing the password** I consider it something not being done properly by Microsoft...

Comment: @ChuckNorris can break encryption just by staring at it.